# Question closed due to incorrect assumptions

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I asked this question:

[Extension causes 404 Error from the Admin Panel](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76470/extension-causes-404-error-from-the-admin-panel)

Several people decided that my problems were caused by the patch SUPEE-6285, and they marked my question as a duplicate.

However my problems weren't caused by this patch (they seem to have been caused by an earlier patch).

What can I do to have this question re-opened? Or should I just ask the question again?

Any advice on this situation would be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a comment explaining that your problem is different.
Or better, you can edit the question and explain you issue.
After a few minutes the question will appear in the reopen votes queue and it might get opened.
Once you reach 500 rep points you will have the option to vote to reopen you question and if it receives enough votes it will be reopened.

If nothing works you can delete your question and ask it again, just be sure to state that the problem is not caused by the latest patch.

I reopened the question this time. It looks like a valid one to me.

Comment: I added a comment and edited my question, but there was no change, which is why I came here. Many thanks for re-opening my question!